# How to combine two OR statements with QueryDSL?

Tags: java, querydsl

How to make the following statement in QueryDSL **`A OR (B AND C)`** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a **Person Entity** as follows

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private Integer age;

    // Getter, Setter, Constructors as required

}
```

You have a **query** object like below

```
QPerson personA = new QPerson("a");
QPerson personB = new QPerson("b");
QPerson personC = new QPerson("c");
```

> Assuming all are Person class query object

You can create a **Predicate** like below

```
BooleanExpression A = personA.username.eq("X");
BooleanExpression B = personB.username.eq("Y");
BooleanExpression C = personC.username.eq("Z");
```

Then you can combine the **BooleanExpression (Predicate)** like below

**`A.or(B.and(C))`**